# How to organize CakePHP project on github that began with git clone CakePHP?

Tags: git, cakephp, github

I'd like to organize my personal CakePHP 2.x projects on my GitHub account. But since I begin a new project with "git clone..." the new project already has git artifacts. Assuming all of my application code is under app/, and I don't need/want to commit core CakePHP files, items brought in by composer, etc., what's the best way to structure my project, initialize it with git, and place it on GitHub?

Checking stackoverflow, I see answers to how to structure empty folders, etc. My question is simply how to start a CakePHP 2.x project with GitHub being the master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation already has a guide on how to do that. [See this link.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#installing-cakephp-with-composer)

You can use git sub modules instead of composer as well, but I would use composer. Just don't forget to ignore the vendor folder in your .gitignore and plugins that have been added via composer as well.

Where ever and however you install the core, just make sure your app can find it. Taken from the official documentation:

> By default bake will hard-code CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH. To make your
>   application more portable you should modify webroot/index.php,
>   changing CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH to be a relative path:

```
define(
    'CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH',
    ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . 'Vendor' . DS . 'cakephp' . DS . 'cakephp' . DS . 'lib'
);
```

Comment: Aha! The answer, if I understand you correctly, is to start the project by installing CakePHP via composer dependency, rather than by using git clone. If this is what you mean, I'll vote this up and mark it answered. Thanks!

Comment: Composer is the best way to mange it today IMO. You could just clone the repo as well and remove what you don't need as well. The page I've linked describes also how to set the path to another core location.